# How to prevent reciprocal primary key - foreign key relationships?

Tags: plsql, triggers, check-constraints

Assume an employees table like the one in Oracle's HR sample schema. It includes the following:

```
CREATE TABLE employees
(
  employee_id     NUMBER(6)       NOT NULL    PRIMARY KEY,
  ...
  manager_id      NUMBER(6)
);

ALTER TABLE employees
ADD CONSTRAINT employee_manager_fk
FOREIGN KEY (manager_id)
REFERENCES employees(employee_id);
```

I want to prevent a reciprocal relationship: if the employee with id 110 reports to the employee with id 110, I don't want to allow employee 110 to report to employee 100. I want to prevent the following:

```
employee_id     manager_id
100             110
110             100
```

I don't think this is doable with a constraint, because it would require a subquery. So, I think a trigger is necessary. This is only a concern on an UPDATE as it's impossible to create this situation with a DELETE or INSERT. I've created the following trigger, which does the job:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER employees_bu_trigger
  BEFORE
    UPDATE OF manager_id
  ON employees
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  l_managers_manager_id employees.manager_id%TYPE;
  reciprocal_managers EXCEPTION;
  -- This prevents ORA-04091: table C##HR.EMPLOYEES
  -- is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION; 
BEGIN
  SELECT manager_id
  INTO l_managers_manager_id
  FROM employees
  WHERE employee_id = :new.manager_id;

  IF l_managers_manager_id = :new.employee_id THEN
    RAISE reciprocal_managers;
  END IF;

EXCEPTION
  WHEN reciprocal_managers THEN
    -- re-raise the error to be caught by calling code
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20102,
                            'Employees cannot manage each other.');
END;
```

But I'm worried about the `PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;` line. That's needed to prevent the `ORA-04091` error, but it makes me think there might be some further underlying problem here.

Is this trigger okay or will it have unforeseen negative side effects?

Comment: Do you only care about looking one-level ahead, or should you recursively look at the entire tree of managers?  What if the boss's boss's boss is set incorrectly?  I have a feeling you'll need to run a recursive SQL statement on the entire table, in an AFTER trigger, to fully protect the table.

Comment: @JonHeller yes, you're right. But still, same question.

Comment: In case anyone wants to see the recursive solution @JonHeller mentions, I've put one here: https://github.com/WebucatorTraining/Oracle/blob/master/check-manager.sql

Answer (score 0):

The danger of the `PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION` is that it runs in a separate transaction. So if your active transaction just added a entry and then before committing you do the update, this trigger will not see the inserted record and will allow records that violate your rule. This problem also occurs with other concurrent users (i.e. if user a makes an update in a transaction and user b makes an update the check will pass for both of them, but once they both commit the error state can exist even though both checks passed.)
Also while the example provided does not have this problem (as [Oracle's documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25054_01/server.1111/e25789/consist.htm#i5704) states that `A writer never blocks a reader.`), there is a danger of deadlocks if you do any writes in the trigger.
It may be possible to refactor your check to be a AFTER trigger without the FOR EACH ROW.
This will eliminate the danger of deadlocks, and of the test passing in the single user case.  **BUT** it will not eliminate the multiuser issue.

Jon Heller's comment on multilevel loops may also be relevant to our specific problem, but any changes to the checks do not impact the issues you were specifically asking about.

Comment: To clarify, you're saying that the following scenario would cause a problem, correct?
1. Employee ID 2 reports to employee ID 1.
2. Employee ID 3 reports to employee ID 2.
3. UPDATE employee id 3 to report to employee id 1, but don't commit.
4. UPDATE employee id 2 to report to employee id 3. This causes an error when it shouldn't, because it still thinks that employee id 3 reports to employee id 2.

Comment: yes, but it gets worse, if you change step 4 to UPDATE employee 1 to report to employee id 3, it won't error, and after both commits you will have 1->3 and 3->1.

Comment: Using PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION to prevent a mutating table error is basically a design philosophy of "If you have a bad design that results in a run-time error then turn it into a bug and hide it." Yea I know that's an opinion, but  pragma autonomous_transaction causes so many more problems than it solves and they are extremely hard to find, especially when the problem crops up 6 mo - 1 yr later.